# Run transactionally and retrieve result in Future

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

How to run a `transactionally` statement in Slick 3.1.x, and capture the result in a Future (without the use of Await)?

This works (but uses Await)

```
 val action = db.run((for {
      _ <- table1.filter(_.id1 === id).delete
      _ <- table2.filter(_.id2=== id).delete
    } yield ()).transactionally)
    val result = Await.result(action, Duration.Inf)
```

However this does not print anything:

```
val future = db.run((for {
      _ <- table1.filter(_.id1 === id).delete
      _ <- table2.filter(_.id2=== id).delete
    } yield ()).transactionally)
 future.map { result => println("result:"+result) }
```

**UPDATE**

This is the real code taken from the program that doesn't work. It prints "1" but it never prints "2"

```
case class UserRole (sk: Int, name: String)

class UserRoleDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRole](tag, "user_roles") {
  def sk = column[Int]("sk", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = (sk, name) <>  ((UserRole.apply _).tupled, UserRole.unapply)
}

class Test extends Controller  {

  def index = Action.async { request =>

    val db = Database.forConfig("db1")
    val userRoles = TableQuery[UserRoleDB]
    val ur = UserRole(1002,"aaa")

    try {

          val action = (for {
                  userRole2 <- userRoles += ur
              } yield (userRole2)).transactionally

          val future = db.run(action)
          println(1)
//        val result = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
          future.map { result => {
             println(2)
             Ok("Finished OK")
           }
          }
      } 
      finally db.close

  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Maybe app exits before future completes. Try adding some `Thread.sleep` after mapping future to see that it works.

Comment: For a side effecting function (returning `Unit`) like `println` it is better to use `foreach` (instead of `map`).

Comment: if `future.map` doesn't kick in it's because the future is probably a failed one, try attaching a `.recover` or `.recoverWith`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from the [other question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925036/slick-transactionally-future-is-not-invoked-in-play-for-scala): You are opening and then immediately closing the db connection in the `finally` clause. Therefore your async db operation runs against a closed db connection. That's also why it works by using `Await` since that blocks the execution of `db.close` until you received the result set.

**So how to fix this?**

Either you move `db.close` into `future.map` or better you let [play-slick](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick) handle db connections for you.

**Side note**

You should close your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925036/slick-transactionally-future-is-not-invoked-in-play-for-scala) and update this thread accordingly instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is fine. My guess is that you are either running it in standalone program or in test - and it simply finishes before future has a chance to be executed.

Try to add some sleep *after* your code in your second sample and you'll see it is getting printed. This is *definitely* not something (this sleep) you would do in your actual code but it will show you it works as it should.

Comment: I'm running this in Play 2.5, not standalone. For some reason the `future.map` is not executed

Comment: Could you paste bigger piece of code? Like how this interacts with your controller handling in Play?

Comment: As @PNeyens suggested try adding recover (although you said it works with `Await.result()` so it shouldn't be the problem but lets be sure...).

Apart from that - is this piece of code:

```
  future.map { result => {
     println(2)
       UpdateOk(result.sk)
   }
  }
```
what is returned from your controller?

Comment: [Please see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925036/slick-transactionally-future-is-not-invoked-in-play-for-scala), I made a self contained code that replicates the problem