# Slick Transactionally future is not invoked in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-2.5, slick-3.0

The code below prints '1' and never prints '2', as a result the browser hangs when it requests the page served by the `index` method. The future is never invoked. If the `future.map` statement is replaced with `Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)` the code works correctly. What is the problem?

```
case class UserRole (sk: Int, name: String)

class UserRoleDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRole](tag, "user_roles") {
  def sk = column[Int]("sk", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = (sk, name) <>  ((UserRole.apply _).tupled, UserRole.unapply)
}

class Test extends Controller  {

  def index = Action.async { request =>

    val db = Database.forConfig("db1")
    val userRoles = TableQuery[UserRoleDB]
    val ur = UserRole(1002,"aaa")

    try {

          val action = (for {
                  userRole2 <- userRoles += ur
              } yield (userRole2)).transactionally

          val future = db.run(action)
          println(1)
//        val result = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
          future.map { result => {
             println(2)
             Ok("Finished OK")
           }
          }
      } 
      finally db.close

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't create db connection on each http request. 
Second your finally clause executes probably before you future has chance to be executed and this may be the reason of your problem.

Other than that, it's looking good. Try to initialize resource on application startup or via DI, close db on application stop and then see if problem still occurs.

Comment: problem was that the connection was closed before the future.map was executed.